# R2dbc Repositories always null with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, project-reactor, spring-data-r2dbc

I am trying to test a service, but the Repository is always null. When using a JPA repository, I never had this issue. I am not sure if it has something to do with ReactiveCrudRepository. Has anyone encountered this issue?

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    class UserTest {
    

        @InjectMocks
        private UserService underTest;
  
        @Mock
        private  UserRepository userRepository;

        @Mock
        private AutoCloseable closeable;
    
        @BeforeEach
        public void init() {
            closeable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        }
    
        @AfterEach
        public void closeService() throws Exception {
            closeable.close();
        }
    
        @Test
        void getApplicableUsers() {

    
            when(userRepository.findAll().collectList().block()).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());
            Set<User> expected = underTest.getUsers(getUser(), getUsers());
    
            verify(underTest, times(1)).updateUsers(getUser(),expected);
    
        }
    
    }
```

---

```
>     error
>     
>     java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.user.UserServiceTest.updateUsers(UserService.java:99)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>       at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
>       at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
>       at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>       at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>       at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:135)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>       at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>       at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
>       at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
>       at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

------------- update 1 -------

I figured out what the issue was but not the solution. If I use .block it is always null, however in this case I need to use block. Has anyone been able to use block or optionalBlock() and been able to mock it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAll()` method is not mocked, thus a null value is returned. You should mock `userRepository.findAll()` instead of `userRepository.findAll().collectList().block()`.

Try this:

```
when(userRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(Flux.empty());
```

Comment: If I do it like this then I will have to return Flux or mono depending on the repository call. I was asking how can I mock it when .block is used.

Comment: @Mike3355 You do not need to change the code being tested. You can still use `block` there. You don't really need to mock `block` but `findAll()`.

Comment: I did but it is sadly still null

Comment: @Mike3355 It would really help if you could show the method being tested.

Comment: would you like to chat?

Comment: @Mike3355 sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239825/discussion-between-lkatiforis-and-mike3355).

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify your service class and see do you have any constructor but don’t have your repo in constructor. Either you need to remove constructor or initialize your service object using repo that is coming as null. I had this issue today ; I removed constructor and it worked.